# Subsetting/filtering using brackets and pipes in R

Tags: r, filter, pipe, brackets

I can't get pipes and brackets `[]` to work together. I suspect I am not understanding how pipes work.

I am trying to answer the following question, using brackets and pipes:
What is the name of the country, that was the richest in 1952? (data is from package `gapminder`)

I have tried:

```
1. df[df$year == 1970,] %>% df[df$money == max(df$money),]["country"]

2. df %>% filter(year=="1970") %>% df[df$money == max(df$money),]["country"]

3. df %>% filter(year=="1970") %>% filter(money == max(df$money))
```

Using it without pipes - all lines work seperately. I am not looking for another solution to the problem, but rather to understand pipes and brackets better, and to use these to solve the problem.
For 1. and 2. I get the error saying `Error in xj[i] : invalid subscript type 'list'`, whilst for 3 I get an empty dataframe which puzzles me.

Comment: Your question says finding the richest country in __1952__. Why do you use a condition `year == 1970`? In the `gapminder` dataframe, there is no 1970. So whatever filter you try you will still get a zero-row dataframe as a result.

Comment: I was in fact looking for 1952, the 1970 in this post is a mistake. Doesn't work for 1952 either. Well seen, though

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are a few different ways to solve this which are more readable. However if you want to use pipes and brackets to understand how they work, then the following code should do that. You were almost there. You can use the '.' operator which represents the output of the last process before the pipe to carry forward

```
df[df$year == 1970,] %>% 
  .[.$money == max(.$money),] %>% 
  .["country"]
```

Comment: Thanks - very glad it helped - please could you accept the solution so that users in the future with a similar problems will be directed to it.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are almost there.

Try this:

```
df %>% filter(year == 1970) %>% filter(money == max(money))
```

you do not need the `df$` part. The last option probably returns and empty df because the highest money in the total data frame was observed in a year other than 1970. Also year is probably numeric, so should be used without quotation marks.

Comment: That is a good answer - thank you.
However, it doesn't bring me much closer to understanding why the other two solutions do not work. It is a recurring problem for me. Do you know what is wrong with 1. and 2.?

Comment: I think it is explained in the other answer. in a pipe you carry forward a certain dataframe to next function. You can see `[]` as a function in this case. So if you start with a df before the first pipe, you do not need to introduce it again after the first pipe, because the pipe carries forward the output of the function before the pipe. if you want to use a combination of brackets and pipes (somewhat odd to do) you need to introduce the `.`.  This is a decent chapter on it: https://moderndive.com/3-wrangling.html